# Add a powershell command inside a powershell command

Tags: powershell

I want to run a powershell command in a powershell command.

```
echo "i have {echo 5} mangoes."

I want output like: i have 5 mangoes.
```

Is there any way to solve the issue?

Comment: Use the subexpression operator `$(...)`: `echo "i have $(echo 5) mangoes"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell's string expansion routine respects [the subexpression operator `$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#subexpression-operator--):

```
echo "i have $(echo 5) mangoes."
```

Answer (score 0):

The other typical situation on a command line to get expression vs argument mode using parentheses:

```
echo (echo 5)
5
```